# Is using a shared_ptr to share variables between class and its member objects a good solution?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I did this for share the `learning_rate` between all my neurons :

```
class neural_network {
public:
  neural_network(float learning_rate = 0.005f)
      : learning_rate(new float(learning_rate)){};
  shared_ptr<float> learning_rate;

private:
  vector<neuron> neurons;
};

class neuron {
public:
  neuron(const float learning_rate) {
    this->learningRate = make_shared<float>(learningRate);
  };

private:
  const shared_ptr<const float> learning_rate;
};
```

Is this a good solution to have same `learning_rate` on all my neurons?

Comment: Will `learning_rate` have shared ownership? Then using a shared pointer probably makes sense. But maybe not in this case? Is it really worth having a pointer to a single floating point valuer, shared or not? When the value needs to be "shared" can't you just copy the value?

Comment: On another note, the code you show will not build, you can't assign to a `const` variable. You need to initialize the member variable in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that suggests that anything will be shared with anything else. Either your code sample is insufficient to demonstrate that, or you don't have the concept of shared pointers quite right. Just because two apparently unrelated classes have the same class member with the same name and type, this doesn't establish any kind of relationship between them, in any shape or matter.

Comment: When I change my `learning_rate`, I want the `learning_rate` of all my neurons to be changed too. But is not it a bit too much for just a float?

Comment: Perhaps `learning_rate` should be a *class* member instead? I.e. be a `static` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is reasonably expensive, I don't see the need for it here, only the network needs to "own" the learning rate. Don't be afraid to use raw pointers where appropriate, just avoid `new` and `delete`:

```
class neuron {
public:
    neuron(const float& learning_rate)
        : learning_rate(&learning_rate){};

private:
    const float* learning_rate;
};

class neural_network {
public:
    neural_network(float learning_rate = 0.005f)
        : learning_rate(learning_rate){};
    float learning_rate;

    void make_neuron()
    {
        neurons.push_back(neuron(learning_rate));
    }

private:
    vector<neuron> neurons;
};
```

Comment: Yes but in this case when I change the `learning_rate` of neraul_network, the `learning_rate` of neurons don't change. Therefore I need a additionnal method to change my `learning_rate` everywhere.

Comment: No, the neurons are storing a pointer to the networks learning rate, changes to the network member will be reflected in the neurons

Answer (score 2):

`shared_ptr` is to share ownership, not to "share an instance".

There is a well defined relation between lifetime of some instance `X` and its members. In the easiest case the members will be alive till they are destroyed in `X`s destructor. Members typically do not stay alive beyond the lifetime of `X`. Hence, there is no need for shared ownership. You could use raw pointers to emphasize that the `neurons` do not participate in the ownership of `learning_rate`.

```
class neural_network
{
public:
    neural_network(float learning_rate = 0.005f)
        : learning_rate(learnin_rate) {};
    float learning_rate;
private:
    vector<neuron> neurons;
}

class neuron
{
public:
    neuron(const float* learning_rate) : learning_rate(learning_rate){}
private:
    const float* learning_rate;
}
```

PS: Not sure, but I think I would apply a rather different design. Make `learning_rate` a (non-const non-pointer) member of `neurons`. Then if the `neural_network` changes the `learning_rate` it would call the neurons `set_learning_rate` method to update their learning rate. In this way `neuron`s have a chance to react when the learning rate changes.

Comment: The "raw pointer means I don't own it" idiom doesn't work so well in mixed "old/new" pointer code.  In a new class using both smart and raw pointers, one can have at least some confidence that the raw pointers aren't just hold-overs of pre-*_ptr-code.  A comment or naming convention can make it explicit and remove the need for guesswork (and reduce the number of double-delete bugs when someone else comes along and "fixes the leak").

Comment: @MarkStorer partly understand, but `learning_rate` would be a `float` in `neural_network` so no problem there. `neurons` just get a raw pointer passed and trying to call `delete` on a raw pointer you dont know where it came from never was a good idea, so also no problem in `neuron`

Comment: `learning_rate` always come from neural_network because class neuron is only instantiate inside neural_network. I never create neurons alone.

Comment: @MatthieuH thats fine. I dont really understand to what part of my answer you refer to with that comment. Is there anything I wrote that is in contrast to neuron only being created by neural_network?

Comment: I guess my point is that unless you're in a codebase that uses that idiom consistently, it's Helpful to be explicit when a raw pointer doesn't own what it's pointing to.  `const *` is one way, Hungarian-esque naming conventions are another, as is ending the pointer's name with something like "NoOwn". Even when the author is the only person to ever look at the source, the author-six-months-from-now isn't going to remember every little detail, so do that future version of yourself a favor and be explicit when you use "raw doesn't own" pointers in code that doesn't always use that idiom.

Comment: @MarkStorer sorry I still dont get your point `void foo (T* t) { delete t;}` is and always has been a red flag. deleting a pointer you dont know where it came from requires lots of care and perhaps comments, but in the code is posted i see no danger. If someone comes along to refactor a `delete learning_rate` in `neuron` they are simply doing something wrong

Comment: Granted.  I've learned a number of defensive programming habits over the (mumble) years of my career.  They're always in the spirit of "if I do this, I'll never have to worry about that kind of bug".  This may well be one of the habits I picked up before ever running into that kind of bug in the first place.

Comment: @MarkStorer If I declare my `learning_rate` like as a `float const * const`, it's rather clear that the raw pointer doesn't own what it's pointing to.

Comment: @MarkStorer still dont get what you are trying to say. Is there anything you would propose to change on the code I posted? (warning: I will not accept adding comments or use some naming convention, to my experience over the years ... they rarely helped to prevent a bug)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 No, I think your code is solid.  I also think `const *` (as you have written) covers the bases.  I'm simply trying to warn @MatthieuH that introducing a new idiom in a small corner of an existing codebase can lead to (human) reader confusion, which can lead to bugs. I have no idea how big his team or codebase is.

Comment: @MarkStorer as I already said, `void foo (T* t) { delete t;}` being a red flag is not a new idiom, independent of the existance of smart pointers such function shouldnt pass a code review ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I've found that comments and naming conventions help readability *outside a good IDE* quite a bit.  *Inside*, all you usually need is a keyboard shortcut or a mouse hover.  But when code ends up in emails, here on SO, in various code review systems, a chat program, or in a sub-par IDE, having naming conventions and comments can help quite a bit. YMMV (and clearly does).

Answer (score 0):

For a single `float`, I really think all this is overkill.  If your learning rate could grow more complex, that's one thing, but in the code given here?  I suggest just going with a float member in `neural_network`, and a `const neural_network* owner;` in `neuron` set during construction.

Then you slap a public `getLearningRate()` on `neural_network` and you're done.  And you might have all sorts of network-wide state to track, so the individual neurons can get a lot of utility out of that one pointer.  Examples might be logs, a serialization stream, or maybe a dirty flag.

> Bonus: No dynamic allocations, which is always a nice efficiency gain when you can get it.  No pointer-related cache misses, no `new`ing or `delete`ing.

Furthermore, I'd think your call to `make_shared()` in `neuron`'s constructor will create a new shared pointer, pointing to a new instance of that same `float` value.  This results in changes to the root `learning_rate` not affecting the existing `neuron` instances at all.  (and a lot of extra, unwanted memory allocation)